# Диапазон double в Random

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно задать диапазон для `Random` от 0 до 0.001?

Comment: Что такое "диапазон для массива"? Но вообще вопрос выглядит так как будто вам нужно обычное умножение.

Comment: Я имею ввиду простой диапазон,в пределах которого формируются числа.

Answer (score 5):

Для того чтобы получить случайное значение от `0` (включительно) до `0.001` (не включительно), можно результат вызова метода `NextDouble` домножить на `0.001`:

```
var rand = new Random();
var result = rand.NextDouble() * 0.001;
```

---

В общем случае, когда нижняя границы не равна нулю, решение выглядит так:

```
var min = 0.001;
var max = 0.003;
var rand = new Random();
var result = rand.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
```

И в виде extension-a для `Random`:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static double NextDouble(this Random random, double min, double max)
    {
        return random.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Напишите еще про общий случай, типа `a * r + b`, чтобы можно было закрывать все подобные вопросы как дубли этого

Comment: @Андрей да, как раз занимаюсь этим.

Comment: На всякий случай предупреждаю, что связка `var rand = new Random(); rand.NextDouble()` - это не тот сценарий использования на который данный класс рассчитан